# Print first character of string results in segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I am trying to use `printf` to print the first character of the string `str_1` to stdout in `x86-assembly` within a `64bit` `Ubuntu 20` environment, here is my attempt:

```
; nasm -f test.asm && gcc -m32 -o test test.asm.o
section .text
global  main
extern printf

some_proc:
    mov esi, str_1

    mov eax, [esi]
    push eax
    push argv_str
    call printf

    pop eax
    ret

main:
    call some_proc

    ret

section  .data
    str_1        db `three`
    argv_str     db `%c\n`
```

This outputs:

```
t
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Expected stdout:

```
t
```

Why is this code resulting in segmentation fault and how do I modify the code to output the expected stdout?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where the fault actually occurs?

Comment: By having your entry point be `_start`, you're bypassing all of the standard library's initialization code, and so you can't expect any standard library functions such as `printf` to work properly.  This is only appropriate for programs that don't need the C library at all, and will do all of their work through raw system calls.  If you need the C library then you need to have your program's entry point be `main`.

Comment: You have another bug in that `mov eax, [esi]` loads 4 bytes when you only want 1.

Comment: Oh, but the bug that probably actually causes your crash is that you push arguments on the stack for printf, and it's your responsibility to pop them back off, but you don't.

Comment: How do I only load a single byte? Ever after changing the code's entry point to `main` and compiling with `gcc` I still receive a segmentation fault.

Comment: @NateEldredge I modified my example to represent what you recommended. Still I receive the same stdout.

Comment: You pushed twice but popped only once.  In order for `ret` to return to the right place, the stack needs to be back in exactly the same state as when the function was entered.  The call to `printf` does likewise; unlike in some other calling conventions, it doesn't remove its arguments from the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several bugs:

- You push two 4-byte arguments onto the stack for `printf`.  In SysV calling conventions, `printf` will leave them there, and so it is your responsibility to adjust the stack afterwards to "remove" them.  Remember that `ret` will look for a return address at the top of the stack; as your code stands, what will be there is the character value from `eax` that you pushed.  That's not a valid address, so trying to return there causes a segfault.  You can remove those arguments by `pop`ping twice, or more efficiently by simply adding `8` to `esp`, thus moving the stack pointer back to where it was.
- Current versions of the i386 SysV ABI require the stack to be aligned to 16 bytes just before `call`ing any function.  Thinking about the fact that `call` itself pushes 4 bytes on the stack as the return address, as does every `push` instruction, you can work out the necessary adjustments needed for your calls to `some_proc` and to `printf`, and add or subtract from `esp` as appropriate.  (Technically you could avoid aligning the stack before calling `some_proc` and just fix it up before `printf`, but this is too easy to screw up.)  Some 32-bit libraries may be compiled in such a way that this requirement is not enforced, but 64-bit code definitely needs it, so it is a good habit to comply.
- `esi` is a callee-saved register according to [i386 SysV ABI calling conventions](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI) (memorize these!).  If you want to modify it, you have to save the previous contents and restore them before returning (e.g. `push esi` at the top of the function and `pop esi` at the end).  Or choose a caller-saved register such as `ecx` instead.  However, as noted below, you don't really need to use a register for the address of `str1` at all.
- `mov eax, [esi]` is a 32-bit load because `eax` is a 32-bit register.  So this will load `eax` with the 4 bytes from location `str_1`, which will result in it containing the value `0x65726874` (the bytes `t h r e` as a little-endian integer).  This may not actually cause a problem since `printf` is supposed to convert its `int` argument back to `unsigned char` for printing, so you should only get the low byte `0x74 = 't'`, but it is still weird, and could break if your string was very short and adjacent to an unmapped page.

  Safer would be `mov al, [esi]` which just loads one byte into `al`, which is the low byte of `eax`,  but whatever garbage is in the high 3 bytes will stay there.  You could zero out `eax` beforehand with `xor eax, eax`, but you can also kill two birds with one stone with the `movzx` instruction, which zero-extends a smaller operand into a larger one: `movzx eax, byte [esi]`.

  Of course, putting the address into `esi` first is redundant, since the address can be specified as an immediate: `mov al, [str_1]` or `movzx eax, byte [str_1]`.  This then avoids the need to save/restore `esi`.
- `main` is expected to return an exit code, and return values always go in `eax`.  Your `eax` would contain your characters or maybe the return value from `printf`, depending where your push/pops end up.  Any of those will be a weird nonzero exit code and your shell will think the program encountered an error.  So zero out `eax` before returning from `main`, to indicate success.
- `argv_str` is a strange name for a string that has nothing to do with `argv`.

I would modify your program as follows:

```
; nasm -f test.asm && gcc -m32 -o test test.asm.o
section .text
global  main
extern printf

some_proc:
    sub esp, 4 ; 8 more bytes pushed before call to printf
    movzx eax, byte [str_1]
    push eax
    push argv_str
    call printf
    add esp, 12
    ret

main:
    sub esp, 12
    call some_proc
    xor eax, eax
    add esp, 12
    ret

section  .data
    str_1        db `three`
    argv_str     db `%c\n`
```

Comment: How does one know exactly how much you should increment/decrement the stack before calling functions/procedures?

Comment: @dnsis_445: Basically, you think about how to get it to be a multiple of 16, based on what other changes you have made to the stack pointer.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64729675/634919 and dozens of other questions on this site about stack alignment.